# Selecting first and last number of consecutive series, then when it finds skip, do same for next series?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a point shapefile which contains integers in a field of the attribute table. It has 1001 consecutive numbers until 1232, then 2001 until 2545, 3001-3240, etc.
I would like to select first and last of each series.
Any expression for that?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate values in your attributes? Also, could you provide a simplified example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: No, I don't have any duplicate value. This is for Seismic Lines. They name a point with an unique number, and each line starts with a unique number as well. For example Line 1000, then the station can be 50, It would be 1050. Line 2000, 3000, etc. But also sometimes we have a skip in a line. For example. A line can go from 1001 to 1500, then stops and starts again 1535 then all the way trough 1600. I used to have a software for this, but now I only have ARCGIS. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Here's some Python that might help:

```py
import itertools
import operator

def chunks(L):
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(L), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        yield map(operator.itemgetter(1), g)

L = [1230, 1231, 1232, 1233, 2001, 2002, 2003, 3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3005]

for g in chunks(L):
    print g[0], g[-1]
```

Note: may not be peformant for very large lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method (hack) that will perform the following actions:

1. Create a list of integer sequences from a field ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361991/1446289))
2. Select only the first and last sequence
3. Match the OID with the sequence list--create a new list
4. Select the FC OIDs that match the OID list
5. Write a new FC from the selection

Keep in mind this method has several assumptions:

1. Values are integers
2. Duplicate values will be included in the final output
3. There is more than 1 sequence in the attributes

---

```
import arcpy, os
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\featureclass'
outfc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\out_featureclass'

# Create a list of sequences from your field
l = []
data = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, 'FID_test_aoi3_lakes') if isinstance(row[0], int)]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): i-x):
    l.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))

# Clean l1 to remove single items and sort sequences
l2 = sorted(x for x in l if len(x) > 1)

# Combine the first and last sequences
l3 = l2[0] + l2[-1]

# Now get the corresponding OID
l4 = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['OID@', 'FID_test_aoi3_lakes']) if row[1] in l3]

# go through each row and select OID that matches l4 list items
fclyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "fclyr")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fclyr, ['OID@', 'FID_test_aoi3_lakes']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in l4:
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fclyr, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", where_clause = '"FID_test_aoi3_lakes" = %s' % row[0])
    # Write the selected features to a new FC
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fclyr, outfc)
```